# Is it possible to use my Lightning Web Components in my external web page through Lightning Out JS?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I created a small LWC, and I need to "plug" it in my angular web page, can I use Lightning out javascript in my angular page ?

I did it with Aura component and it works well, but Wondering if possible with LWC.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep your aura component as a "empty shell" and embed your LWC in it :)

Example:

```
<!-- auraComponent.cmp file -->
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <lightning:card title="Aura Hello World" iconName="custom:custom30" />
    <c:lwcHelloWorld name="Earthling" />
</aura:component>
```

Doc: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition

Comment: Ok Nicolas thank you, I'll test it right now :)

Comment: you're welcome, please let me know if it works ^^ ( i don't use LWC yet ^^ ) :)

Comment: It works well, now wondering if I can declare a variable in my Aura, and use this var in my LWC (which is inside my Aura) ?

Comment: Great :) Just send the variable as a parameter to your lwc component ?
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:attribute name="myVar" type="String" />
    <c:lwcHelloWorld name="{!v.myVar}" />
</aura:component>

Comment: Hi, Nicolas (sorry for delay) yes variables con be passed from aura to LWC, but I'm still wondering how to ambedd my LWC within my angular app ? (without any aura)

Comment: this is another question ^^ I'm not sure Salesforce likes to be directly included in another app without a community ... So the question may be "how to embed a community in an angular app"  ^^